# Arithmetic exception with rand() and mod

Tags: c++, modular-arithmetic

Twice now my server has crashed after several days of running on this line.

```
int randomValue = rand() % m_list.size();
```

where m_list is

```
std::list<int> m_list;
```

The crash is

```
Program terminated with signal 8, Arithmetic exception.
```

getting the size of a list should be guaranteed to not be negative. What could cause this crash? Can something with rand be the cause? I seed rand at the start of my server with

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps the size of the list is... **zero**?!

Comment: `SIGFPE  8 Core Floating point exception.` A division by zero seems the most likely culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have that much information about the situation, but does the list have anything in it? If not, you'd be dividing by zero, and that would explain everything.

So, first step is to make sure that m_list is not zero.

If it is, perhaps you could check to make sure that the size of the list is not zero before performing the operation.

Comment: Welp, I feel silly. I don't know why I didn't think about that. That is definitely the problem, thanks guys! I will accept answer as soon as I can.